# Is there a way to compare button images in Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I've looked around and I don't think there's a way to do this, but what I'm looking for is the ability to compare button images. I have a situation where I want to see if the button is set to a certain image before I change it. The pseudocode would be something like

```
if (myCell.followButton.image == UIImage(named: "")) {
//do something here
}
```

Comment: among how many images can it be?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Updated for iOS 8 thanks to kakubei

`UIButton` has a property called `currentImage`, so use that to compare the images:

**iOS 8+**

```
if myCell.followButton.currentImage.isEqual(UIImage(named: "yourImageName")) {
    //do something here
}
```

**iOS 7-**

```
if (myCell.followButton.currentImage == UIImage(named: "yourImageName")) {
    //do something here
}
```

A better way to achieve this functionality would be to keep track of the button's selected state and change its image based on that. That would make it more flexible if you ever change the name of the image.

Comment: Ah wasn't aware that was there, thank you! Can't compare states here because it might not have been selected but it could require a different image based on whether the user is private.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend doing a check directly on if the user is private, rather than the image that might **represent** that the user is private. It's generally preferred to keep track of state with the model, rather than checking the view, as the latter makes the UI brittle and harder to change.

Answer (score 8):

Matt Cooper's solution won't work in iOS 8 because Apple has changed how images are cached. You now need to use `.isEqual`

As in:

```
// assuming both button and newButton are UIImage instances
if button.currentImage!.isEqual(newButton) {
  ...
```

From Apple Docs:

> As of iOS 8, you can no longer rely on pointer equality to compare
>   cached UIImage objects as the caching mechanism may not return the
>   same UIImage object, but will have cached image data separately. You
>   must use isEqual: to correctly test for equality.

The downside of this is that it won't work in iOS 7! I don't know of a way that will work in both but I'm hoping there is, I'm searching for it myself :)

Answer (score 4):

It can be done in following way:

```
   if let btnImage = sender.image(for: .normal),
        let Image = UIImage(named: "firstImage.png"), UIImagePNGRepresentation(btnImage) == UIImagePNGRepresentation(Image)
    {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"secondImage.png"), for: .normal)

    }
   else 
    {
         sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"firstImage.png"), for: .normal)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 13 @Matt Cooper's answer does not work, I'm not sure but other infos are included in the name of the image (maybe changes in the API since 2015), so my comparison always returns false:

```
UIImage: 0x28297e880 named (main: Icon-camera-alt) {20, 20}
```

I've used this in my case:

```
myButton.currentImage?.description.contains("camera-alt")
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure, if you keep the image references you can just do a straight compare. Otherwise, I am not aware of a way.

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you mean by "keep image references" and "straight compare". Also, note that this solution (if I'm guessing what you mean correctly) won't work on iOS 7.

Comment: I meant what you posted. And since IOS7 allows pointer comparisons you just need to condition your comparison based on platform. I would recommend a category to centralize that.